# Android app not appearing in device market despite being compatible

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app (*All operators' APN | Tweakker*) and it's been on the market for a while now. I discovered this week that I can't find it from my device's market anymore although I used to be able to. Nothing in the app has changed. If I go to the web market I get a message that confirms the app is compatible with my Desire. I tried finding the app with other phones as well, even from different countries, and it just doesn't appear.

Here's what I tried so far:

- unpublish, publish
- change promotion preferences
- release a small bugfix update
- wait for the Market to return to normal

Someone suggested the single quote might be a problem, but that can't be the case since this worked up to this week. The app is using copy protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app seems to appear in the market now, although I haven't done anything more. I did contact Google, but I don't have an answer from them yet.